SharePoint List formatting a Date column
I have a SharePoint list with a date column. I want to format the Dates in the column to be centered with Bold Red Text and keep using the existing background color, if the date is within the last 7 days. I would also like to use the hexadecimal code #FF0000 to represent the red, so I can easily alter the color to a different shade of red, if needed.

See if the following works for you
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >=(@now -(86400000 * 7))  && @currentField <= (@now), '#FF0000', '')",    
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}


